# How to override component view to main screen react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create notification screen and I have an icon in the app bar. For the header, I am using "react-native-flat-header". Everything is working fine but on the press of notification icon I need to open a box that will show the list of notifications.

I am trying to show the box screen but it's not showing out of my header component.

I need to design

[image]

Here is my header component:

```
<FlatHeader
    <View style={styles.notification}>
                                        <View style={styles.triangle}/>
                                    </View>
/>
notification:{
        right: 70,
        top:20
    },
    triangle: {
        width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderRightWidth: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 20,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',

        //position:'absolute',
        zIndex: 1,
        position: 'absolute'
    },
```

Comment: I can see the notification box in the screen shot, but I can't see what?

Comment: I need to make the same box and i am totally confused about how to create that because my header component fixed height and the position not working.